# jquery ajax json url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've given up on trying to accomplish my intended objective! I have jquery/ajax code that is as simple as I can get it using web and library. I've been working on this several weeks; thank goodness I'm retired or I'd be without a job! I have never seen so much code that doesn't work on the net today. Most examples don't bother to show the url used in the ajax call! Anyway I've loaded up an htm file and a txt file. Please find something wrong, I am tired of looking, thx.

**htm file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<title>testing</title>

<script src="../jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"test.txt"})
    .success (function(result){ $("#comdisplay").html(result); });
});
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>

<center><button><h3>Click</h3></button></center>

<div id='comdisplay'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**txt file**

```
<h2>howdy folks</h2>
```

That's it, Thanks

Comment: What is the displayed result?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"test.txt"})
    .success (function(result){ $("#comdisplay").html(result); });
});
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({url:"test.txt"})
        .success (function(result){ $("#comdisplay").html(result); });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This should do the trick
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "test.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result) {
            //for debug
            alert(result);
            $("#comdisplay").html(result);
        },
        error: function(e) {
          alert(e)
        }
      });
      //Here's another option
      $("#comdisplay").load("test.txt");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url : 'text.txt',
    type: 'GET',
    success : function(result){ $("#comdisplay").html(result); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Define your function inside document.ready. It is working here with the code below.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            alert("asd");
            $.ajax({ url: "test.txt" })
            .success(function (result) { $("#comdisplay").html(result); });
        });
    })
```